# Replace character to "@" in string

Tags: python, replace

Why python does not replace last character for @?

```
str_manip = input("Enter a sentence ")
last_char = str_manip[-1]
print(last_char)
change_char = str_manip.replace("last_char", "@")
print(change_char)
```

It comes up as exactly the same sentence as I enter, unchanged.

I have read a few websites and still do not understand. I thought maybe it was because @ is char but str() doesn't help, saving it as separate string variable also doesn't work.

Comment: You have `last_char` in quotes in your `replace()` call, so it is looking for the literal string `last_char`.

Comment: You are replacing the *literal string* `last_char`.  To use your variable as the character to be replaced, simply don't put quotes around it.

Comment: `str_manip.replace("last_char", "@")` Here you are passing `last_char` as string. You need to pass a variable named `last_char` i.e. without any quotes as follows `str_manip.replace(last_char, "@")`

Comment: it works! so easy but so hard :D Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
str_manip = input("Enter a sentence ")
last_char = str_manip[-1]
print(last_char)
change_char = str_manip.replace(last_char, "@")
print(change_char)
```

Comment: Thank you! Just did it.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
change_char = str_manip.replace("last_char", "@")
```

by

```
change_char = str_manip.replace(last_char, "@")
```